# Linux / NodeJS get exitcode of process runned by "exec"

Tags: linux, node.js

I need to run g++ compiled program and get exit status. My code in nodejs:

```
import pty from "node-pty";
...

ptyProcess.write("exec /var/www/a.out\r\n'");
```

What I found:

**$!** is the PID of the last process sent to the background

**$?** is the exit code of the last process

It means. I can do in terminal: `/var/www/a.out && echo $?` - result, running program and in the end 0 (Success exit code). Hovewer, exec don't allow to run any commands after it, as once a.out is done, exec closes.

Problem is, I am making web c++ compiler & debugger, and I want to give **exec** output to user (web page) to debug his written code... Once exec is done, he don't get root to whole terminal. If I use **without** exec, then after program is done, he can get **root@server:~#** .. If something is unclear, please ask in comments and I will try to explain better.

UPDATE. OK seems I can use `/var/www/a.out && echo $? && exit`, it is fine when program ends successfully, however if I try to press CTRL+C or CTRL+Z, I can break command and get root. With **exec** when you press these combinations, you don't get root.

UPDATE 2. Okay, so I ended with this:

`trap '' 2 3 20 && /var/www/a.out && echo $? && exit\r\n`

**trap** disables CTRL combinations:

SIGINT=CTRL-C

SIGQUIT=CTRL-\

SIGTSTP=CTRL-Z

Comment: programming question should be asked on [so] because it is associated with programing